Completeness Relation of Hermite-Polynomials
I have this interesting task dealing with hermite polynomials with which I am struggling a bit:
The hermite polynomials $(H_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are defined by $H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$.
Show that the hermite polynomials have the following completness relation:
$$exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{2^nn!\sqrt\pi}=\delta(x-y)$$
Hint: Use fourier transformed gaussian distributions to express the derivatives in the multiplications.

Mehler's formula  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

I'm not clear on your context... do you know that $H_n\cdot e^{-x^2/2}$ is the image of $e^{-x^2/2}$ under a "raising operator"? And that the "quantum harmonic oscillator" $-\del^2+x^2$ has compact resolvent?

@paulgarrett No we should really just use the fourier transform, the definition of the hermite polynomials I gave above and I suppose the generating function should also be necessary
